# Cron Jobs on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform

Am I able to check Cron Jobs when App is deployed?

Locally it is: `localhost:8000/cron`

I was guessing maybe `my-service.my-app.appspot.com/cron`, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Seraf own anser, you have to run

```
gcloud app deploy cron.yaml
```

in order to upload cron tasks, as per:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml?hl=es-419#uploading_cron_jobs

Answer (score 3):

No.  But you can check them in your admin console:

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/taskqueues?project=my-app&tab=CRON

Comment: I uploaded the cron.yaml file alongside the app.yaml file, locally I see the next scheduled tasks but when I go on my app's taskqueues, it's empty. Do you know why? Do I have to do something extra except uploading the cron file? @GAEfan

Comment: Well, have the trigger times passed, so the crons were actually triggered?

Comment: I did let it pass, it had to run Sunday but it didn't. I'll test again now, maybe I had the wrong version. @GAEfan

Comment: I actually had to deploy it alone with gcloud app deploy cron.yaml @GAEfan, case closed